# Computing the expectation of the outer product of two Gaussian vectors

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, expectation

Let $a$ have iid $\mathcal{N}(0,I_n/n)$ entries and fix $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n.$ I would like to compute $$\mathbb{E} \left[1_{\{a \cdot x > 0\}}1_{\{a \cdot y > 0\}}aa^T\right]$$ where $1_A$ is the indicator function on the event $A$. I know that $\mathbb{E}\left[aa^T\right] = I_{n \times n}/n$ since the off diagonal elements ($i \neq j$) are $\mathbb{E}[a_ia_j] = \mathbb{E}[a_i]\mathbb{E}[a_j] = 0$ by independence and the diagonal elements are \begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[a_i^2] = \mathbb{E}\left[\left(a_i - \mathbb{E}[a_i]^2\right)^2\right] = Var[a_i] = 1/n.
\end{align*} However, I am uncertain as how to proceed with the indicator functions involved. I first tried to consider the case when $x = e_1$ and $y = \cos\theta e_1 + \sin \theta e_2$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $x$ and $y$. Then the indicators become $1_{\{a_1 > 0\}}$ and $1_{\{a_1\cos\theta + a_2\sin\theta > 0\}}$ so $\mathbb{E}[1_{\{a_1 > 0\}}] = \mathbb{P}(a_1 > 0) = 1/2$ but I don't know how to compute the probability of the second event. Can anyone provide any hints in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a 2 dimensional problem. Rotate coordinates such that $x_i=y_i=0$ for all $i\ge 3$.  The expectation will be the sum of the interesting part depending on $(a_1,a_2)$ and a multiple of the identity matrix coming from the outer product of $(a_3,\ldots,a_n)$.  For the interesting part, write $(a_1,a_2) = R (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$, where $R$ and $\theta$ are independent, with known distributions.  The restrictions $a\cdot x > 0$ and $b\cdot y>0$ translate into a range restriction on $\theta$.  So the upper 2 by 2 corner of  the answer is of form $$\frac{ER^2}{2\pi} \int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1} \left( \begin{matrix}\cos^2\theta & \cos\theta\,\sin\theta\\\cos\theta\,\sin\theta&\sin^2\theta\end{matrix}\right)\,d\theta.$$

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer! I think this is what I'm looking for. Can I ask how you arose at the conclusion this was a 2-d problem and set $(a_1,a_2) = R(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$?

Comment: The constraint set is the intersection of two half-spaces.  In the $n=3$ case a geometric intuition is possible: you are in effect looking at what's inside a wedge, whose ``blade'' is the line of intersection of the two planes cut out by $a\cdot x=0$ and $a\cdot y=0$.  Rotate so that you are looking at that line, edge-on.  What you see is the $(a_1,a_2)$ behavior; what you don't see is the $(a_3,\ldots,a_n)$ stuff.  The $R$ and $\theta$ stuff is a standard trick.  Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_theorem for details.